# ASP.Net MVC 5 authentication with another MVC 5 Identity website

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

I have crated two MVC 5 websites. First one is with Identity, where I have DB, Facebook and Google authentication enabled. Now I have second empty MVC 5 site that I want to redirect to the first site for authentication. How to redirect for authentication to first site? All other aspects of second website should work as standard, like if I decorate something with `[Authorize]` etc.

**Note**: These can belong to different domains. For example; *mail.live.com* goes to the *login.live.com* for authentication.

Is there a way to create your own OWIN authentication provider like Microsoft provides for Facebook/Google?

Any pointer to the right would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create your own OWIN authentication provider like
>   Microsoft provides for Facebook/Google?

**Yes**, That is possible. Considering that the security is hard, so you need to spend a lot of time to write clean codes. You need to have a good understanding of Open Authentication technologies. Please see [How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work) to understand my meaning.

You can also change the Authentication Strategy to simplify the problem. Take a look at [Single Sign On (SSO) for cross-domain ASP.NET applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114484/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-appl).

You can use the following code if you strongly consider the validity of the resultant absolute returned URL:

```
public class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/account/logout"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider { OnApplyRedirect = ApplyRedirect },
        });
    }

    private static void ApplyRedirect(CookieApplyRedirectContext context) {
        Uri absoluteUri;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(context.RedirectUri, UriKind.Absolute, out absoluteUri)) {
            var path = PathString.FromUriComponent(absoluteUri);
            if (path == context.OwinContext.Request.PathBase + context.Options.LoginPath)
                context.RedirectUri = "http://domain.com/login" +
                    new QueryString(
                        context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter,
                        context.Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
                        // or use context.Request.PathBase + context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString
        }

        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
    }
}
```